# moving to previous window in emacs

Tags: emacs

C-xo
moves you to the next window in emacs, how do you move to the previous window?

I sometimes have up to 10 windows open and it would be great to move in either direction.

Also is there a way to jump to a specific window by number? (jump to the 3rd window for example)

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143072/in-emacs-what-is-the-opposite-function-of-other-window-c-x-o).

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
(defun other-window-backwards (count)
  (interactive "p")
  (other-window (- count)))

(global-set-key [(control meta prior)] 'other-window-backwards)
(global-set-key [(control meta next)]  'other-window)
```

Then use C-M-prior (Page Up) to move to previous window, C-M-next (Page Down).  Flavor bindings to suit!

Answer (score 2):

You can give the command C-x o an argument of -1, like so:
C-u -1 C-x o

That will take you to the previous window

Also to get 3 windows back use:
C-u -3 C-x o

Answer (score 1):

you mean buffers?? if so there are `next-buffer` and `previos-buffer` functions which perform `Switch to the next/previous buffer in cyclic order`.

Edit:
with spong answer. I use windmove for window switching.

```
(windmove-default-keybindings) ;; Shift+direction  
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x O") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window -1))) ;; back one
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-o") (lambda () (interactive) (other-window 2))) ;; forward two
```

Comment: I thought what you did, but he actually *did* mean windows.

Comment: @andrewdski Since he said 10 windows I get that thought. as I go more than 4 windows in a frame it gets unmanageable. I should have written as a comment to question instead of an answer.

Comment: @kindahero, Yeah 10 windows does seem pretty crazy!  Maybe we should have simply said "screen shot or you lie"!  :)

Comment: Ok, maybe I exaggerate, but right now I have 6 open. It is the curse of having a large vertical monitor. You just *have* to fully use it. Anyway, I remaped C-x , and C-x . to forward and backward and that works great. (oh and C-x m and C-x / for double moves) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have these lines in my `init.el`:

`;; Use shift key to move between various split windows`

```
(when (fboundp 'windmove-default-keybindings)
(windmove-default-keybindings))
```

This helps me to move between various split windows by using Shift+ arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Bart (and others) have given correct answers for your exact question.  You can also look at `windmove` which should came packaged into the latest Emacsen.